# What is this strange red glowing thing I found in an underground snow biome in terraria?

Tags: xbox-360, terraria-console

i was just mining in this cool underground snow biome (in terraria, Xbox360) and I saw this weird red glowing thing. I looked on the wiki and only found a "demon altar" but it's not the same thing. It looks different than that. I tried mining it with my "hurtful tin pickaxe" but after a minute or 2 it did nothing. It's dark red with 3 bright red glowing pieces in it. It's also 2 blocks wide. It is one ice block away from platinum ore. I started playing a few months ago so I'm not an expert at the game yet. WHAT IS THIS THING?!

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, it's a Crimson Altar.  It's basically the same thing as a Demon Altar.  Crimson Altars show up when there is Crimson present on the map, and Demon Altars show up when there's Corruption on the map (it's either/or).

[image]